# Check the checkboxes between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've a set of checkboxes in a form. Like below,

```
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="main-dish-9">Id 9</label>
</div>
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-12">Id 9</label>
</div>
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-17">Id 9</label>
</div>
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-18">Id 9</label>
</div>
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="main-dish-12">Id 9</label>
</div>
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-11">Id 9</label>
</div>
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-21">Id 9</label>
</div>
```

When a page loads, only the check boxes with the id `main-dish` are enabled, others are read-only. In this case when I click on the checkbox with an id starting with `main-dish`, It should make all the checkboxes below it starting with the id `sub-dishes` to be enabled. If someone checked the `main-dish`, then it also must select any checkbox with an id starting with `sub-dishes`.

```
(jQuery)("input[type='checkbox'][id*='main-dish']", context).click(function () {

  (jQuery)("input[type='checkbox'][id*='sub-dishes-cuisine-category']").prop('disabled', true);

})
```

Comment: "main-list" do you mean " main-dish" ??

Comment: I do not see any relation among them...

Comment: @A.T. Yes, I meant that

Comment: @Rayon, I wanted to know if it is possible.

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Use `nextUntil()` which selects the next elements until it finds the one with the selector of `main-dish`, this function takes as input a list of elements and selects all elements until the label with a id of `main-dish-*`,from there we select the checkbox and we toggle the disabled property

```js
$("input[type='checkbox'][id*='sub-dishes-cuisine-category']").prop('disabled', true);
$("input[type='checkbox'][id*='main-dish']").click(function() {
var inputs = $(this).closest('label').nextUntil($("input[type='checkbox'][id*='main-dish']").closest('label')).find('input');
  
  inputs.prop('disabled', !inputs.prop('disabled'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="main-dish-9">Id 9</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-12">Id 9</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-17">Id 9</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-18">Id 9</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="main-dish-12">Id 9</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-11">Id 9</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-21">Id 9</label>
```

Demo with wrapped div

```js
$("input[type='checkbox'][id*='sub-dishes-cuisine-category']").prop('disabled', true);
$("input[type='checkbox'][id*='main-dish']").click(function() {
  var inputs = $(this).closest('.wrap-input').nextUntil($("input[type='checkbox'][id*='main-dish']").closest('.wrap-input')).find('input');

  inputs.prop('disabled', !inputs.prop('disabled'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-input">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="main-dish-9">Id 9</label>
</div>
<div class="wrap-input">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-12">Id 9</label>
</div>
<div class="wrap-input">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-17">Id 9</label>
</div>
<div class="wrap-input">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-18">Id 9</label>
</div>
<div class="wrap-input">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="main-dish-12">Id 9</label>
</div>
<div class="wrap-input">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-11">Id 9</label>
</div>
<div class="wrap-input">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sub-dishes-cuisine-category-21">Id 9</label>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rayon now you know !

Comment: Hi madalin, I see an issue, the label and input is wrapped inside a div, then how will I do that?

Comment: you change in the closest function the `label` with the class of your wrapping div

Comment: I've tried your answer, but the issue is the checkbox enables only during the click, once the click event is fired, the check boxes become disabled.

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra what do you mean by that?

Comment: ie., the checkbox enabled only for the click event. Once the event is completed, it goes back to the disabled state. I wish I could show you.

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra as you can see from my snippets this shouldn't happen, you must have another script that is interfering with this one

Answer (score 0):

By using `true` you are still disabling the check boxes, it should be set to false

```
(jQuery)("input[type='checkbox'][id*='sub-dishes-cuisine-category']").prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: I guess you were in a rush to answer by the middle of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected = [];
$('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think simplier way to use `class` selectors and wrapper.

Html:

```
<div>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" class="main-dish">Id 9 </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" class="sub-dishes-cuisine" disabled="">Id 9.1 </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" class="sub-dishes-cuisine" disabled="">Id 9.2 </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" class="sub-dishes-cuisine" disabled="">Id 9.3 </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" class="main-dish">Id 10 </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" class="sub-dishes-cuisine" disabled="">Id 10.1 </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" class="sub-dishes-cuisine" disabled="">Id 10.2 </label>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".main-dish").click(function() {
        var $inp = $(this).parent().parent().find(">label>.sub-dishes-cuisine");

      if ($inp.is("[disabled]")){
         $inp.removeAttr('disabled');
      } else {
         $inp.attr('disabled', true);
      }
    })
});
```